# C# change event order

Tags: c#, events

Edit*
ok sorry for not giving the real scenario,

actually i have datagridview created programatically, i put 2 event, which is **mouseclick** and **ColumnHeaderMouseClick**.
currently whenever user click on column header it will trigger **mouseclick** first then followed by **ColumnHeaderMouseClick**

can i change the order of the trigger? or can i know when user click i can check whether he click on column header or other place in "mouseclick event"?

Comment: This is probably not what you want to do. Re-evaluate what it is you really need to accomplish and ask that instead

Comment: Why on earth you want to do that? What problem you're trying to solve? Sounds like a [XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: please refer to my edited question

Comment: What are you doing in mouseclick and ColumnHeaderMouseClick that it matters which comes first?

Comment: in mouse click event if there is row selected it will do something on that row, but problem happen when user havent select anything and click on column header it will do that something also, because by default if you click on column header it will sort the row and auto select/highlgh the 1st or last row, so in column header event i put clear selction but the problem is this event come after mouse click event T_T

Comment: Just put the logic all in the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event handler.

Comment: but all the logic i want it to execute only when user click other than header only, if user click header i dont want to execute the logic except clear the selection

Comment: i got the solution already, i get the index of the row, if -1 its mean it is a header so i can do the if else already, no need for different event, enough with cell-click event alone can handle both scenario.
sorry for asking in complicated way when the solution is so simple, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution already, i get the index of the row, if -1 its mean it is a header so i can do the if else already, no need for different event, enough with cell-click event alone can handle both scenario.
 sorry for asking in complicated way when the solution is so simple, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do that. The events occur according to the events that are actually taking place. In other words, that would be like saying can you walk through a door without opening it first. It doesn't really make sense in the context.

Could you possibly switch the code you are calling for down and click? Or just use click and execute the events in whatever order you like there?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, it does not make logical sense. The `MouseDown` event necessarily occurs prior to the `MouseClick` event because the mouse button had to go down in order to initiate a click. When the mouse button goes down, a `MouseDown` event is raised. The `MouseClick` event cannot be raised until some time *after* that.

The order of the mouse events is [explicitly documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx) and cannot be modified.

And you say that this was just an example, that you are working on other events. Unfortunately, the answer will be the same regardless. The order in which events are raised is something decided by the programmer who wrote the code that raises those events. There is no mechanism for you, the consumer of the library, to change that order.

Like the mouse events discussed above, [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx) lists the order of *all* significant events raised by the WinForms library.

Of course, if *you* are writing the code that raises the events, you can always modify it to raise them in whatever order you want. But I suspect that much is obvious and not why you are asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Most C# implementations will typically fire off the event handlers in the order that they are registered to each event. **However this is not enforced!**

It could change at any time and as such you should not create a dependency on the order of event handlers in your application.

I strongly suggest you take a step back and review your application design for ways to remove this dependency.

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but the terminology you use is confusing. You don't register *events*, you register *event handlers*. Indeed, the order in which event handlers are executed, if they are all subscribed to the same event, is purely an implementation detail. In the current implementation, they are executed in the order they were registered, but this is not guaranteed. It gets especially complicated when you have multi-threaded code; you can't reasonably rely on any order. As for *events*, they are always raised in the order that they are raised in the code.

Comment: Ah indeed that was my intention. I have made the appropriate corrections. Thanks for commenting. Upvoted your answer for more completeness.

Answer (score 0):

As many have suggested on their answers trying to change the event order is not recommended for multiple reasons.

In order to achieve what you want, you would have to re-implement the Windows Forms controls of the .NET Framework.  You can also try to hijack the Windows message processing by overriding the `WndProc` procedure and process directly the messages provided by the OS, but you will learn that the event firing order follows the order in which the OS sends the input provided by the device (mouse) to the affected windows/controls.